# Creating index only for selected values of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to create index for only specific values of a column?

*For instance:*

Lets say, I have a table **employe** with attributes: **employeId, employeName** etc.

And I want to create index only for the employeeNames that starts with **m**. Is that feasible in oracle?

Comment: Yes. It's called a filtered or conditional index. http://dba-presents.com/index.php/oracle/41-filtered-index-equivalent-in-oracle

Comment: There's no real need to do this at all... why not just create an index on `employeename`?

Comment: The example give above is to illustrate the problem. In practice, as you have mentioned its not a good idea to index on specific names.